# If $f:[0, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $f(0) = 0$, then does $\int_0^\pi f(t)\cos nt\,dt = 0$ for $n=0, 1,2,\dots$ imply $f = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[0, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(0) =  0$, then which of the following are true?

1. If $$\int_0^\pi f(t)\cos nt\,dt = 0$$ for $n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$, then $f \equiv  0$
2. If $$\int_0^\pi f(t)\sin nt\,dt = 0$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f \equiv  0$
3. If $$\int_0^\pi t^nf(t)\,dt = 0$$ for $\{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$, then $f \equiv  0$

Comment: By Weierstrass there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ converging uniformly to $f$  on $[0,\pi]$. Therefore, if we assume (3), $0=\int_{0}^{\pi}p_n(x)f(x)dx\to\int_{0}^{\pi}f^2(x)dx$. Therefore, $f$ is zero.

Comment: @orole Wouldn't this involve exchanging the limit and integral, though?
$f_n \rightarrow f $ does not, in general, imply that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^b f_n $ converges to $\int_a^b f$.
**Edit**: My bad, the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for (1) and (2): If $f$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$ then $f$ can be extended to an *even* continuous function on $[-\pi,\pi]$. If $f$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$ and $f(0)=0$ then $f$ can also be extended to an *odd* function continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$. In either case you can use the given information to find $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos(nt)$ and $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\sin(nt)$.